# ngRoute using parameters

Tags: angularjs, parameters, routes, ngroute

I'm still going through the process of learning routes and params. I thought I had it figured it out but not quite there yet.

My idea is to route just a little info about the user when clicked without having a file for each user. This means that I want only one html file which the data it will "load" will be triggered by parameters.

So here's my app.js file:

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module('Platform', []);


    app.controller('getUser', function(){
        this.users = arrayOfUsers;
        });

    var arrayOfUsers = [
    {
        firstName: "George",
        lastName: "Best",
    },
        {
        firstName: "Dame",
        lastName: "Lillard",
    }
    ];

    Platform.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/",
        {
            controller:"getUser",
            templateUrl:"index.html"    
        })
        .when("/users/:user",
        {
            controller:"getUser",
            templateUrl:"UserPartial.html"  
        });
    });
})();
```

my index.html file:

```
<body ng-controller="getUser as users">
...

    <li><a href="users/{{users.users[0].firstName}}">{{users.users[0].firstName}}</a></li>

...
```

I want it like this so that the url matches the username's first name.
I know this involves parameters but I'm not figuring out very well. I know I need to create parameters and use ngRoute but I don't quite know how. Im also uncertain about whether I should or not create another module for using ngRoute.
Thanks for reading :)
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Change `Platform.config(function ($routeProvider) {...` to app.config.

Then, if you need to access the data, inject $route, and access $route.current.params in the single view controller:

```
    app.controller('getUser', function($route){

      // not sure what this is?
      // this.users = arrayOfUsers;

       $route.current.params;

    });
```

Comment: changing to app.config makes the whole thing not to work.

this.users = arrayOfUsers; 

this is an array that stores the users data that will determine the URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$routeParams`.

js

```
var app = angular.module('Platform', ['ngRoute']);
  app.controller('getUser', function($scope, $routeParams){
      this.users = arrayOfUsers;
      $scope.user = $routeParams.user;
   });
```

use it in html

```
<p>{{user}}</p>
```

full html

```
<html ng-app="Platform">
  <head>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="UserPartial.html">
      <span>      Content of the template. </span>
      <p>{{user}}</p>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="index.html">
    </script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="getUser as users">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#/">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/users/George">George</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/users/Dame">Dame</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('Platform', ['ngRoute']);
      app.controller('getUser', function($scope, $routeParams){
          this.users = arrayOfUsers;
          $scope.user = $routeParams.user;
          });

      var arrayOfUsers = [
      {
          firstName: "George",
          lastName: "Best",
      },
          {
          firstName: "Dame",
          lastName: "Lillard",
      }
      ];

      app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider
          .when("/",
          {
              controller:"getUser",
              templateUrl:"index.html"
          })
          .when("/users/:user",
          {
              controller:"getUser",
              templateUrl:"UserPartial.html"
          });
      });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I made this change

 var app = angular.module('Platform', ['ngRoute']);


 app.controller('getUser', function($scope, $routeParams){
  $scope.utilizadores = users;
  $scope.user = $routeParams.user;
  });


I didnt understand the html part.
Could you maybe explain whats being added?

you're saying  "$scope.user = $routeParams.user;", but aren't both variables undefined? How should it work?

Comment: `$routeParams` holds the params defined in `$routeProvider.when(...)`, it is like `{user: "George"}`. In the controller, $scope.user = $routeParams.user` defined a new variable `user` in `$scope`, so you can use it to display in html by angular way {{user}}.       `<span> Content of the template. </span> ` `<p>{{user}}</p>`

Comment: Its not working. It keeps displaying the URL i want .../users/George but then just says "page not found".

Comment: Can you paste UserPartial.html?

Comment: A simple paragraph
<p>connected</p>

shouldnt the $scope.user be defined in the object maybe?

Comment: attached full index.html, hope can help.

Comment: I think that you just clarified most of my doubts! Thank you! One last question, what if the UserPartial.html is a different file? Shouldnt it just load it considering that it is in the same directory?

Comment: yes, usually template is separted in other html file, it will be loaded automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)